# Bash - Retrieving Strings of Text in Files with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, string, bash, text, grep

I'm sorry if the title was poorly worded. Here's the idea. Let's say that I have many files and I wish to find all occurrences of a particular expression such as:

```
tag:"some text I wish to retrieve"
```

Note that the entire line above would appear in the files. I wish to copy only what is in the quotation marks after the word 'tag'.

I'm not an expert at bash by any means, but I could easily use grep to retrieve the entire line that contains the regular expression. Easy. However, I only want part of that line. The text in quotation marks varies in length. Ultimately I want to amalgamate all occurrences into one file.

For instance, I would want to take FILE 1 and FILE 2 and end up with FILE 3:

FILE 1:

```
whatever:"text I don't want" 
something:"More text I don't want" tag:"some text I wish to retrieve"
```

FILE 2:

```
whatever:"don't want" tag:"more text I wish to retrieve" something:"nope"
```

FILE 3:

```
some text I wish to retrieve
more text I wish to retrieve
```

Can this be accomplished using bash? I could do it in C with a bit of effort, but I'd rather not if I don't have to.

EDIT:

"-o" is used to show only the part of the line that matches the expression. I don't know how I missed that in the man page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grep to perform this task.

```
grep -hrPo 'tag:"\K[^"]*' * > result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `gnu awk` (gnu due to multiple characters in RS) version:

```
awk -v RS="tag:" -F\" '{$1=$1} FNR>1 {print $2}' FILE*
some text I wish to retrieve
more text I wish to retrieve
```

---

This should work with all version of `awk`:

```
awk -F\" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~" tag:") print $(i+1)}' FILE*
some text I wish to retrieve
more text I wish to retrieve
```